# How to use CFStreams using GCD

Tags: ios, sockets

I am a newbie to ios..

I want to connect to a server using Socket Connection, i followed the tutorial given
[here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server)

This works fine, but the i was doing everything in the main UI Thread,but the view was getting freezed till i get a response from server... So i googled a little and found the concept of GCD in ios... So on my button click i call the following code...

```
    [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Processing.."];
    [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];


  qt = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(qt, ^{
CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)ip, 54000, &readStream, &writeStream);

inputStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
outputStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
[inputStream setDelegate:self];
[outputStream setDelegate:self];

[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

[inputStream open];
[outputStream open];

NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[pinno dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
[outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
[outputStream close];
    });
```

And I am handling events using the function

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent {

    NSLog(@"StreamEvent %i",streamEvent);
    switch (streamEvent) {

                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{[SVProgressHUD dismiss];
            });

        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
            NSLog(@"Stream opened");
            break;

        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
                 NSLog(@"Stream has byte Avaliable");

            if (theStream==inputStream) {

                while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
                    uint8_t buffer[1024];
                    int len;
                    len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
                    if(len>0){
                        NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
                        [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

                        NSLog(@"output %@",output);


                    }
                }
            }
            break;

        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
            [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

            NSLog(@"Can not connect to the host!");
            break;

        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
            [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

            break;

        default:
            [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

            NSLog(@"Unknown event");

    }
}
```

Using the above code i get a request to the server and the server also sends a successful response,but i don't receive any data in the handle event method,but i am not getting a hasbytesavaliable event.. my console log is

```
2013-07-02 14:06:15.312 Multi[899:1c03] StreamEvent 1
2013-07-02 14:06:15.313 Multi[899:1c03] Stream opened
2013-07-02 14:06:15.313 Multi[899:1c03] StreamEvent 4
2013-07-02 14:06:15.313 Multi[899:1c03] Unknown event
```

Any idea what i am doing wrong...

```
Edit:Updated Code
```

On button click i start the timer and call the connect method..

```
counter=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30.0 target:self selector:@selector(stream:handleEvent:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];


        qt = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
        dispatch_async(qt, ^{[self connect];});
```

Connect method:

```
  CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)ip, 54000, &readStream, &writeStream);


    inputStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
    outputStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;

    NSRunLoop *loop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];

    [inputStream setDelegate:self];
    [outputStream setDelegate:self];

    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:loop forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:loop forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    [inputStream open];
    [outputStream open];

    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[pinno dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
    [outputStream close];

    [loop run];
```

The stream handle event

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent {
    Username.text = @"";
    Password.text = @"";
    [self disconnect];
    if (counter!=nil){
        [counter invalidate];
        counter=nil;
    }

    NSLog(@"StreamEvent %i",streamEvent);
    switch (streamEvent) {

        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
            NSLog(@"Stream opened");
            break;

        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
            if (theStream==inputStream) {

                while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
                    uint8_t buffer[1024];
                    int len;
                    len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
                    if(len>0){
                        NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

                        NSLog(@"output %@",output);
                        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
                        main = [[Mainmenu alloc]
                                initWithNibName:@"Mainmenu"
                                bundle:nil];
                        //                        [self.view addSubview:main.view];
                        [self presentViewController:main animated:NO completion:NO];
                    }
                }
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{[SVProgressHUD dismiss];
            });

            break;

        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:

            NSLog(@"Can not connect to the host!");
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{[self dismiss:@"Cannot connect to host!"];
            });

            break;

        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{[self dismiss:@"Connection Error"];
            });

            break;

        default:
            NSLog(@"Unknown event");
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{[self dismiss:@"Timeout Expired"];
            });

    }
}
```

And the disconnect method..

```
-(void) disconnect
{
    [inputStream close];
    [inputStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outputStream close];
    [outputStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [inputStream setDelegate:nil];
    inputStream = nil;
    [outputStream setDelegate:nil];
    outputStream = nil;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are running it on a separate thread then you must take care of the Run Loop. You have to call the

> [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];

at the right time.

Change your this part of code as below and it will work for sure:

```
inputStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
outputStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;

NSRunLoop *loop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];

[inputStream setDelegate:self];
[outputStream setDelegate:self];

[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:loop forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:loop forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

[inputStream open];
[outputStream open];

[loop run];
```

Comment: Thanks a million man... from 2 days i m struggling with this problem... can you please do me another favour... I need to know how will i timeout the connection after 30seconds..

Comment: What do you mean by timeout here....do you mean if server not responding then timeout after 30 sec?

Comment: oK.. got a solution i used NStimer for expiring the connection after 30seconds...But I'm not sure this is the proper recommended method,but it still works.. i have updated my code...